# Unordered list not 'moving down' when hidden <li> are shown

Tags: html, css

I have created a menu using an unordered list. However when I want to show a submenu that I have hidden they simply go underneath the unhidden list items.

What I need is when the hidden list items become shown using :hover I need it to 'push down' the other list items.

Here is the code

```css
#navigation ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  max-width: 50%;
  height: 1000px;
  display: none;
}
#navigation ul li {
  width: 300px;
  height: 40px;
  display: block;
  background-color: blue;
}
#navigation li ul li {
  background-color: purple;
  width: 300px;
  height: 40px;
  display: block;
  clear: both;
  margin-top: 2px;
  padding-bottom: 2px;
  display: none;
}
#navigation ul li:hover ul li {
  display: block;
  float: none;
}
.menu {
  width: 300px;
  background: blue;
  color: white;
  height: 30px;
}
input[type=checkbox] {
  display: none;
}
input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ #navigation ul {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<label for="menu" class="menu">Show Menu</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="menu" role="button"></input>
<nav id='navigation'>
  <ul>
    <li><a href='#'>Products</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href='#'>Book Returns & Trolleys</a> 
        </li>
        <li><a href='#'>Furniture</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href='#'>Kingfisher Display</a> 
        </li>
        <li><a href='#'>Kinfisher Kidz</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href='#'>Library Shelving </a>
        </li>
        <li><a href='#'>Seating</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href='#'>Whiteboards & Noticeboards</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href='#'>Projects</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href='#'>Contact</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href='#'>About</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href='#'>Specials</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Thankyou.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were a few issues here. The biggest being you added `height: 40px` to `#navigation ul li` which is why your subnav was not pushing the other `li`s down. It was contained within a `40px` box and just breaking out. You really should add a `class` to your `ul`s because some styles become inherited when you necessarily don't want them too. Also you need to show the subnav on the `ul` hover and not the `li` or you're going to have a large gap:

```
#navigation ul.nav { //added class name to ul
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  max-width: 50%;
  height: 1000px;
  display: none;
}

#navigation ul.nav li {
  width: 300px;
  display: block;
  background-color: blue;
}

#navigation ul.nav li ul.subnav{ //added class to subnav
  display: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#navigation ul.nav li ul.subnav li {
  background-color: purple;
  width: 300px;
  height: 40px;
  display: block;
  clear: both;
  margin-top: 2px;
  padding-bottom: 2px;
}

#navigation ul.nav li:hover ul.subnav {
  display: block;
}

.menu {
  width: 300px;
  background: blue;
  color: white;
  height: 30px;
}

input[type=checkbox] {
  display: none;
}

input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ #navigation ul.nav {
  display: block;
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/s7w2ueah/)

Answer (score 1):

most of the styles were overwritten because you have use `ul` `li` for styling so i have used `>` selector which will only target the child not sub-child

```css
ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
a {
  color: white;
  display: inline-block;
}
#navigation > ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  max-width: 50%;
  height: 1000px;
  display: none;
}
#navigation > ul > li {
  width: 300px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: blue;
  display: inline-block;
}
#navigation li ul {
  width: 300px;
  display: none;
}
#navigation li ul li {
  height: 40px;
  background-color: purple;
  display: block;
  clear: both;
  margin-top: 2px;
  padding-bottom: 2px;
}
#navigation ul li:hover ul {
  display: block;
  float: none;
}
.menu {
  width: 300px;
  background: blue;
  color: white;
  height: 30px;
}
input[type=checkbox] {
  display: none;
}
input[type=checkbox]:checked + #navigation > ul {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<label for="menu" class="menu">Show Menu</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="menu" role="button"></input>
<nav id='navigation'>
  <ul>
    <li><a href='#'>Products</a>

      <ul>
        <li><a href='#'>Book Returns & Trolleys</a> 
        </li>
        <li><a href='#'>Furniture</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href='#'>Kingfisher Display</a> 
        </li>
        <li><a href='#'>Kinfisher Kidz</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href='#'>Library Shelving </a>

        </li>
        <li><a href='#'>Seating</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href='#'>Whiteboards & Noticeboards</a>

        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href='#'>Projects</a>

    </li>
    <li><a href='#'>Contact</a>

    </li>
    <li><a href='#'>About</a>

    </li>
    <li><a href='#'>Specials</a>

    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `display: inline` to `#navigation ul li`.

**Working Code Snippet:**

```css
#navigation ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  max-width: 50%;
  height: 1000px;
  display: none;
}
#navigation ul li {
  width: 300px;
  height: 40px;
  display: inline;
  background-color: blue;
}
#navigation ul li ul li {
  background-color: white;
  width: 300px;
  height: 40px;
  display: block;
  clear: both;
  margin-top: 2px;
  padding-bottom: 2px;
  display: none;
}
#navigation ul li:hover ul li {
  display: block;
  float: none;
}
.menu {
  width: 300px;
  background: blue;
  color: white;
  height: 30px;
}
input[type=checkbox] {
  display: none;
}
input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ #navigation ul {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<label for="menu" class="menu">Show Menu</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="menu" role="button"></input>
<nav id='navigation'>
  <ul>
    <li><a href='#'>Products</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href='#'>Book Returns & Trolleys</a> 
        </li>
        <li><a href='#'>Furniture</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href='#'>Kingfisher Display</a> 
        </li>
        <li><a href='#'>Kinfisher Kidz</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href='#'>Library Shelving </a>
        </li>
        <li><a href='#'>Seating</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href='#'>Whiteboards & Noticeboards</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href='#'>Projects</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href='#'>Contact</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href='#'>About</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href='#'>Specials</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```